# How to configure path alias in webpack.mix?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, laravel-mix

**Solution:**

Thanks to both Karl & Ali I can now use `alias'` without having to create a seperate `webpack.config.js` file. Just add the `alias` to `webpack.mix.js` like so:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
    .alias({'@': 'resources/'})
    .webpackConfig({resolve: {alias: {'@': path.resolve('resources/')}}})
    .vue();
```

**Question:**

From [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/how-to-shortcut-the-path-to-the-assets-directory-in-vuejs-spa), I learned that you could configure your `@` path in `webpack.mix.js` to represent the `assets/resources` folder in a `vue/laravel` project so that you can use the `@` symbol in your paths.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@resources': path.resolve('resources'),
    },
  },
})
```

Unfortunately, this leads to the following error.

> yarn run v1.22.17 $ mix watch [webpack-cli] ReferenceError: path is
> not defined
> at Object. (/Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/webpack.mix.js:16:21)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at module.exports (/Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:11:5)
> at loadConfigByPath (/Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1747:27)
> at async Promise.all (index 0) error Command failed with exit code 2.

I've tried different variations (`@assets` etc.), but I always get the same error. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you import the path previously e.g. using `const path = require('path')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your webpack.mix.js:

```
...
.alias({'@': 'resources/js'})
...
```

[Import Aliases - Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/inertia-and-spa-techniques/episodes/1)

Comment: This will probably work in most use cases beware if you ever try to run mix from a directory outside your project root or if you run it and set a different working directory since it may not work in that case

Comment: Some might prefer `~` instead of `@` since the latter may be used as `scope` context in NPM (e.g. `@npm/package-name`). Related: https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes

Answer (score 7):

The error message indicates that the `path` module is not defined. This module is a core Node.js module used for handling and transforming file paths. You can require it at the top of your `webpack.mix.js` file like this:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ])
   .webpackConfig({
       resolve: {
           alias: {
               '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
           },
       },
   });
```

In this code, `const path = require('path');` requires the `path` module, and `path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js')` generates an absolute path to the `resources/js` directory. The `@` alias now represents this directory, and you can use it in your import statements.

Comment: The thread I've posted mentioned,  that this should work without having to create a seperate `webpack.config.js` file. Is there a way to just use `webpack.mix.js`?